# VSIX and item templates

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix

So I'm having some trouble creating an item template and would like some help.

What I'm trying to do:

Create a template that adds 3 files. A Class.cs and two config files in the location "./Config/Acc/Config.xml" and "./Config/Prod/Config.xml".

I've managed to create the template through the wizard and editing the resulting files, but I would like an easy method of distributing the template on my teams TFS.

From some googling it seems that I should use A VSIX project to deply this easily. Problem is that I can't get it to compile. I have 2 projects: VSIXproject and ItemTemplateProject. I've set the assembly info on VSIX project to use the ItemTemplateProject and I've modified my Class.cs, but when I compile, visual studio doesn't know how to handle the Class.cs file.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way of including my ItemTemplate so that anyone who pulls the repo can use it?

Comment: The template project is only used to contain templates so they will ultimately be added to the .VSIX file output (its own .dll output will not be used). So, you will only have to distribute the resulting VSIX. .cs files in this template project must have their action set to None, not Compile

Comment: @SimonMourier I already have the build action set to None. Still tries to compile the .cs file and gives me errors

Comment: @SimonMourier Ok, so the problem was that my XML files needed to be set to build action None too. If you post it as an answer I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template project (a project that only contains Visual Studio project templates or item templates) is only used to be able to work with templates. Its output (say [myproject].dll) is not important (the project type may be C# but it's irrelevant) and you will only distribute the .vsix file in the end.

Files (.vstemplate files and any other files) in this project are like "static" files. They will also ultimately be included into the .vsix file output during build.

So, to ensure this files (.cs or other) are "static", you must make sure they have their action set to `None` (for example), not `Compile`.

Comment: Hi Simon, I have itemtemplate included in the vsix package. After installed on VS exp instance, I don't see the item template listed anywhere. Do you have any idea of that?

Comment: @Vincent - you should ask another question